# Bullets disappear in nested lists when using \newenvironment

Tags: lists, environments

I am trying to typeset interviews using lists. I have created environments for questions and answers to style the `\item`s and their contained text.

However, if I try to use these environments within a nested list (or a [covington](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/covington) example), all the item labels but the first one suddenly disappear.

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage,a4paper]{article}

\newenvironment{question}{\item[Q:]}{}
\newenvironment{answer}{\item[A:]}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item
\begin{itemize}
\begin{question} Text \end{question}
\begin{answer} Text \end{answer}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Should produce:

```
* Q: Text
  A: Text
```

But `A:` is missing:

```
* Q: Text
     Text
```

If use a plain `\item` instead of my `question` environment, all goes well. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't simply use `\newcommand{\question}{\item[Q:]}` and similarly for `\answer`.

Comment: I'd like to have my question text in italics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are grouping the first item and so an important information doesn't reach the second:

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage,a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{question}{\item[Q:]}{\aftergroup\@noparitemfalse}
\newenvironment{answer}{\item[A:]abc}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item 
\begin{itemize}
\begin{question} Text \end{question}
\begin{answer} Text \end{answer}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```